# json.swift error is Self.init isn't called on all paths in delegating initializer

Tags: ios, json, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3ay8.png)

errors such as the photo came out in json.swift

I don't know how to fix it.
 please help me

```
    public convenience init(nsurl:NSURL) {
    var enc:NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
    let err:NSError?

    do {
        let str: String? = try NSString(contentsOfURL: nsurl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
        //print(str)

        self.init(nsurl:nsurl)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        //print(error.description)

    }
}
```

Comment: paste your code not image

Comment: You have to either make the constructor throwable, removing do-catch clause or call `super.init(nsurl:)`  in the catch block.

Comment: Thank you i!   i try to super.init(nsurl:nsurl) write in a catch clause. 

  but  this error is appeared ['super' members cannot be referenced in a root class]  and [Convenience initializer for 'JSON' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here depend on your intention.

If you just wont your object to be crated and print addition info during init you can rewrite you code like this.

```
public convenience init(nsurl:NSURL) {       
 var enc:NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
 let err:NSError?

 self.init(nsurl:nsurl)
 do {
       let str: String? = try NSString(contentsOfURL: nsurl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
       print(str)

    } catch let error as NSError {
       print(error.description)
    }
}
```

Another option is to have [failable](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) initializer. For this you need call self.init(nsurl:nsurl) if do block performed without exception otherwise return nil from catch block. Also you need to mark you convenience init method as failable (see "?" after init word)

```
public convenience init?(nsurl:NSURL) {       
 var enc:NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
 let err:NSError?

    do {
       self.init(nsurl:nsurl)
       let str: String? = try NSString(contentsOfURL: nsurl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
       print(str)

    } catch let error as NSError {
       print(error.description)
       return nil
    }
}
```